# React navigation Tab in Stack with button in Header

Tags: react-navigation

I'd like to have a TabNavigator embedded in a StackNavigator with a button in the Header used to navigate in the main Stack.

Here is a snack of my issue: https://snack.expo.io/@guigui64/tabs-in-stack

The propblem is when I create the TabNavigator:

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA,
    ScreenB,
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'Title when in tab',
      headerRight: (
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('C')} // here is the issue !
          title="ScreenC"
        />
      ),
    },
  }
);
```

I also tried creating a Component with static navigationOptions and have render() return a TabNavigator. In this case, the header appears fine but not the tabs.

Thanks in advance !